# (discord.js) Add role to "user"

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is there a way to get "member" from "user"?
I use slash command and i want to add role to a member. But there is no way to find member in slash command. Here the way how I find user.

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser('user')
```

when i try

```js
user.roles.add(role id)
```

some error occur:

```
user.roles.add(role id)
           ^
"add" is not a function
```

Comment: Try console.log(user.roles) see if that's working properly

Comment: Maybe you can else use `getMember` instead of `getUser`?

Comment: ITS SOLVED THANKS FOR COMMENTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the user through `interaction.options`, you receive a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object. But to add roles, you need a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) object. So you have to change user to:

```js
const user = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.options.getUser('user').id)
```

**Easier Way**

At the time of writing the answer, I didn't know we could do this but you can just use `interaction.options.getMember('user')` to get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) details of the mentioned user. Even if you use `.addUserOption` to add the option, this method would work. So you can do this:

```js
const user = interaction.options.getMember('user')
```